# How to detect multiple tapping buttons

Tags: android, button, touch

Actually my problem is  I am making custom dial pad in android I pressed one button and I want to press one more button to get the value of that button  I am getting first button value only. When I remove completely finger from first button that time only I am able to press second button

Comment: you should put up some code

Comment: just 2 buttons i am taking i am getting value from edittext when i press buttons. when i press first button i am unable to press second button